# restrict access to chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to restrict access to chrome extensions page like the picture below?
[image: http://s6.picofile.com/file/8184311976/2015_04_03_163820.jpg]

A chrome extension to prevent users to install or uninstall and deactive other extensions without having correct password.

Comment: not through a chrome extension anyway afaik

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @Xan A Valid use case may be to not letting anybody un-install a chrome extension from this page. An extension which do not have any icon can probably be uninstalled from this page

Comment: a chrome extension to prevent users to install or uninstall and deactive other extensions without having correct password.

Comment: @Xan - my use case is to prevent disabling or removing chrome extension that blocks websites/social media etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extensions cannot touch any WebUI (`chrome://`) pages for security reasons.

**Chrome devs work hard to prevent any extension from being hard to uninstall**; your idea specifically goes against this and will fail.

Moreover, if an "Installed by a third party" extension is removed, it's blacklisted and will not install automatically again.

---

If you need to do this for one particular machine, you can enable the "Extensions on chrome:// URLs" flag at `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` that bypasses this restriction, and formally allows you to modify that page.

This requires manual intervention to enable, and there are many, many ways to bypass this block for a knowledgeable user (uncluding overriding this flag), so at most it's a "child lock"/experiment. It's also a security risk, since it enables it for all extensions.

---

The only real way to protect an extension from being uninstalled or disabled is an enterprise policy. [`ExtensionInstallForceList`](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) allows to add extensions that cannot be disabled or removed.

Since it's a possible vector for malware, on Windows it can only be configured in Group Policy for machines connected to a domain.

Comment: could you tell me more about it and how to impement it:"The only real way to protect an extension from being uninstalled or disabled is an enterprise policy. ExtensionInstallForceList allows to add extensions that cannot be disabled or removed.

Since it's a possible vector for malware, on Windows it can only be configured in Group Policy for machines connected to a domain."

Comment: This is about enterprise policy. If your computers are part of a Windows Domain (i.e. you have a Windows Server acting as a AD controller), and you have admin rights for the domain, you can adjust the policy as explained by the link in the post. If it's not the case, then there is no way to activate this feature.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that on Linux and Mac, there is no domain requirement; the policy can be provided by a preference file on the machine.

Comment: You can now easily setup a Enterprise Policy using admin.google.com, which will prevent any extension from being disabled or removed. But there is no way to prevent the user from disabling the extension in private browsing, and/or modifying any of its settings, so it is usually an experiment in futility.

Comment: @SamGoody If it's an extension you control, at least there's `chrome.storage.managed` for managed settings. But private browsing is an interesting question. I suppose one could disable Incognito through policies, if one really, really needs an extension active at all times.

Comment: Why is it so hard to do such a simple thing? I find the plethora of documents at [support.google.com](https://support.google.com) confusing as hell and driven by every little feature of Google Enterprise instead of by the most common use case scenarios. I want to password-lock Chrome extensions on my child's Chromebook so that he cannot uninstall BlockSite. I am stuck with a "legacy" G Suite account, not enterprise, and not family either. I don't have 500 users, just a single Chromebook where I want to prevent my kid to uninstall one extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to block an extension from being removed in Chrome and managed to achieve it easily by just adding a registry key for Chrome.

After adding the key you can no longer turn the extension off, nor can you remove the extension either on the extensions page or the extensions drop down menu.

**Prevent removing Chrome extension with following steps:**

1. In the first step, you can use the Search box, Run Command box, or some other option to launch Registry Editor.
2. After that, access the Policies key in Registry Editor. The path is:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies
3. In the next step, create a new Registry key under this Policies key and set its name as Google.
4. Now, create another key in Google key, and name it Chrome. Again, create a new key under that Chrome key, and set the name to ExtensionInstallForcelist.
5. Under that last key, create a new String Value and give it a name say 1. You can create this value by doing a right-click on the empty area, selecting the New menu, and then clicking on the String Value option. When the value is created, rename it to 1.

   Do not close Registry Editor yet.
6. On the Chrome Extensions page, you can see the extension ID for all the extensions. Copy ID of an extension that you want to prevent from uninstallation.
7. Go back to Registry Editor and double-click on ExtensionInstallForcelist String Value that you created above. In the Value data field, paste the extension ID. After that, append the following text:

   ;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx
8. Press the OK button.

   Now relaunch Chrome browser and access Extensions page.

   You will notice that the Remove button is not visible for that particular extension. Also, when you will right-click on that extension icon, then the Remove from Chrome option won’t visible.

   That simply means the option to uninstall that particular Chrome extension is disabled.

   You can follow the above steps to prevent the uninstallation of any other extension installed on your browser. Just extension ID and the text mentioned above are needed.

   To undo the changes, simply follow the above steps, and delete any String value you created and uninstallation prevention for that specific extension will be removed.

   That’s all!

   Ref: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-uninstallation-of-chrome-extensions